# How to I add a line feed to a title style tooltip in firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, standards-compliance

Firefox does not seem to support line feeds in the title attribute.  I have tried `\r`, `\r\n`, `\n`, `&#xD;`, `&#10;`, and still found nothing that works.

Does anyone have a hack to get around this?

Comment: Do any of these work in other browsers?

Comment: @Oded I am not sure if all of the work, but some do.  I used \n for IE.  I had to kind of remake the wheel to get tiptools to work the way I wanted in Firefox.

Comment: I guess FF is open source, maybe I could go change it, lol.

Comment: I am kind of hoping your a FF developer, and can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing is the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3) about how exactly browsers *have* to display the value in title attributes.

Is simply says:

> Values of the title attribute **may** be rendered by user agents in a variety of ways. For instance, visual browsers **frequently** display the title as a "tool tip"

(Emphasis mine)

So, not only is there nothing about line breaks, but the actual behavior of "tool tip" is not mandatory.

Comment: Honestly, I think w3, should man up and admit IE beat them on this one.  What kind of text don't include end line.  Am I working with Ed or something?

Comment: @Grae - w3 left quite a lot of things to implementers to decide. I would say your gripe is with Mozilla, not w3.

Comment: Well, I have heard else where w3 specs require all \n's to replaced with spaces in title text.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't support this. On other browsers like Chrome, just use return.

```
<a href="..." title="My

long

title">My link</a>
```

Alternatively you could use the [JQuery Tooltip Plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/). It works in all browsers and let's you use html in your tooltips.

Comment: I've added the link to the Jquery plugin. I just tested it, and it works great in Firefox.